# PayPal donation form with a new style (big amount edit box)

Tags: paypal, donations

I have seen that many projects that accept PayPal donation have a donation from with a new design, which looks like this:

[image]

And its URL is like:
`https://www.paypal.com/donate/?token=...`

But I could not find how to set up such donation form.

The *"Create Button"* tool create a code that shows a form with the classic design:

[image]

And its URL is like:
`https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?...`

How do I create a Donation buttons that link to the new design form? Is there a special variable that I can add to the button code to make it link to the new design form?

*(Note that I do not have a PayPal Business account – in case it is relevant.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal controls which page style they display; you do not.

The type of account you have, and the country of that account, and the country and user agent (desktop vs. mobile) of the person clicking the button, are all relevant to which server PayPal routes the request to and which page style they display.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do have any reference for this? I wonder if upgrading to business account would help.

Comment: Upgrading to a business account is free and might help, no harm in trying. However, if you are not in a "major" western country, I would be more concerned about that being the potential cause.  PayPal's systems are very large and available in over 100 countries -- they release new features/styles/UIs to certain countries first, not all at once.

Comment: Not sure when exactly it did happen. But now I indeed get the new style page.